# How to make `apt-get upgrade` use less resources?

Tags: apt

When I run `sudo apt-get upgrade` with a lot of packages on my low-end
laptop, I get a perceptible system slowdown, sometimes with up to 3
second screen freezes.

Is there any way to mark this job as very low priority, i.e.  use very
little CPU, MEM and HDD? I don't really care if it would make `apt-get upgrade` two hours longer to finish, I just want to keep working
without the disruptions during the upgrade.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The command `nice` can be used to manipulate process **CPU scheduling priorities**. The command assigns a "niceness" value from -20 (most important) to +19 (least important) to the process. Root can assign any value, other users only positive ones (minor importance). The default value is 0.

```
nice -n <niceness> <command>
```

To set the priority of an apt-get command to the least value, you can use the command

```
sudo nice -n 19 apt-get upgrade
```

---

To set the priority of an already running process, the command `renice` can be used:

```
renice -n <niceness> -p <pid>
```

---

Edit: Thanks to @David for mentioning the `ionice` command, which lets you manipulate **disk I/O priority**. It can put a process into three different classes:

- **Idle** only gives the process disk time, if no other process claims it at the moment.
- **Best-effort** (default class). This allows you to assign priorities from 0 to 7, where 0 is most important and 7 least. You may try assigning `-n 7` as the priority level.
- **Realtime** processes are handled before everything else, suspending disk I/O for other processes, as soon as they require it for themselves. **Use with care!**

IOnice combines the syntax of nice and renice:

```
ionice [-c class] [-n level] command             #To start a new process
ionice [-c class] [-n level] -p pid              #To change a running process
```

---

Both commands can be combined, e.g.

```
sudo ionice -n 7 nice -n 19 apt-get upgrade      #Omitting the -c switch will assign Best-effort
sudo nice -n 19 ionice -n 7 apt-get upgrade
nice -n 19 ionice -n 7 sudo apt-get upgrade
...
```

Comment: I'm surprised this got so many upvotes. apt-get upgrade is IO bound!

Comment: It was accepted, so I guess it worked...

Comment: how about `ionice`?

Comment: So, to clarify, the `sudo` in your command is not for `nice`, but for `apt-get` itself? It seems that `nice -n 19 sudo apt-get upgrade` also works for me. Is there any important difference?

Comment: @WChargin No important difference in this case, but that's almost worth asking as a separate question on its own as it could be in others (although maybe on Unix & Linux as it's not Ubuntu specific).

Comment: @WChargin `sudo nice apt-get` runs nice as root and will allow setting lower priorities than 0. apt-get will still run as root. `nice sudo apt-get` will run nice as the current user, and thus allow only priorities higher than or equal 0. apt-get will be started as root.

Comment: @David I added ionice to my answer.